# Is there any difference between HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR?

Tags: php

I am trying to get client IP in php
I am facing two issues-

1. I am getting public IP in HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR.Is it different from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?
2. I am not able to get correct IP address in REMOTE_ADDR.

Comment: _"I am not able to get correct IP address in REMOTE_ADDR."_ - probably because you are getting it in HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR. Those "alternatives" get explicitly provided in cases where there is a proxy involved or something like that - _because_  REMOTE_ADDR would be the proxy's IP in such a case.

Comment: My guess is that `HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR` the same is as `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, but just spelled differently.

Comment: Using these headers has security implications because they can be set to anything by the client. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790/369143

Comment: @CBroe so should I retrieve IP from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR if there is some proxy or what should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790/1427878

Comment: @BramVerstraten I read it and i think there is nothing more specific we can do for proxy